# AAPT error: error: mismatched tag. I do not know what else to do

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I keep getting a type mis-match error, and I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly.
*C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\Project\app\src\main\res\layout\fragment_login.xml:50: AAPT: error: mismatched tag.*

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>


    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/senha"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="#F8E9FD"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="40dp">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete tag that closes itself due to the `/` at the end of it:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then on line 5, you have a second closing tag for that already closed tag:

```
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText>
```

Since the tag is already closed, you're getting the error that you're getting.

Either remove the `/` from the end of the opening tag definition or get rid of line 5.